# iOS: How to split images/assets and code so that we can changes assets to make different projects

Tags: ios, bundle

iOS: How to split images/assets and code so that we can changes assets to make different projects.

Objective: I want to make a generic framework in iOS for some image project such that i just need to change the assets(images,texts,fonts), source code should be same and should check number of images/texts etc...

I could achieve this in Android by making library for source code and adding this lib plus changing assets in app project.

I am new to iOS and not sure how to achieve same.

Comment: Read this.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html